# Having problem in passing variables between two forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm almost a beginner of vb.net and I have to do some codes. I want to call a button click in form 2 from another class, i.e., form 1 and the problem is that the variables which defined as pubic, their values don't pass between two forms. My code simply presented as follows:

```
Public class form2

Public Property ResponseTime1 As String

Public Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
Responsetime2 = 20
End sub

End class
```

---

```
Pub class form1

Dim Resposetime as string
Dim z as new form2


 Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    z.button1_click(sender, e)
    ResponseTime = form2.ResponseTime2
    MsgBox(ResponseTime)   '' show nothing????????????

 End sub
End class
```

I would be appreciated if someone helps me

Comment: You should ask for your result to the _z_ variable. The one that you have instanced

Comment: The code provided isn't written properly. Make sure you write that properly then we can troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that `Responsetime2` is never declared. A few spelling errors are further messing up the code. Even if I stick a Dim in front of `Responsetime2 = 20` it is still not visible to from1. Just because a method is public doesn't mean that vaiables inside the method are visible. Even if it was visible, `Responsetime2 is an Integer and you have declared Responsetime as a String.

It is not a good idea to call an event procedure from another class. Event procedures are meant to respond to an event and are private by default. Make the code a separate public method and call it from both form2.button1_Click and form1.

```
Public Class form25

    Public Property ResponseTime2 As Integer

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        SetResponseTime2()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetResponseTime2()
        ResponseTime2 = 20
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class form15

    Dim Responsetime As Integer
    Dim z As New form25


    Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        z.SetResponseTime2()
        Responsetime = z.ResponseTime2
        MsgBox(Responsetime.ToString)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're right, I made some spelling errors in declaring the variable ResponseTime2 . Thank you for your explanation, I will change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dear I have no idea why you made this `Public Property ResponseTime1 As String` most probably you have a reason for it but i am going to show for you how i would do it

Form1 Code

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    form2.show
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(Form2.ResponseTime)
End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 code

```
Public Class Form2
Public ResponseTime As String
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ResponseTime = "test"
End Sub
```

End Class

I tested this one and its working
Hope i could help to you